# Copied Android Project - APK Installer clash

Tags: android, installation, apk

I wanted to create a variation of my android project (for debugging purposes) so I copied it in eclipse, and renamed a few things (the project name, class etc, project name in build.xml)

It builds a different named APK, however when I install this APK, it uninstalls the original app, and visa versa.

I noticed in logcat

D/ActivityManager( 1853): Trying to launch applicationName

When I try and launch the 'other' app, from a short cut on the home screen it says 'application is not installed on your phone'

As if some property has not been set, but I can't find where applicationName is set (though this may be a red-herring).

SO my question is really, if I copy an android-sdk project, what settings should I be changing to make sure it its really a separate application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to change package in android manifest it need not to same as the java package you can name it anything you want it is android package name which is used to identify apk by android.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="" android:versionCode="" android:versionName="">
```

Comment: I thought that might be something to do with it, so I changed one from com.redskyit.mobile to com.redskyit.mobile.rmcv2dev but it didn't seem to solve the problem.  However I have just re-visited it, and set the other one to com.redskyit.mobile.rmcv2 and both now install without clashing with the other, so I must have done something wrong first time around.  And just to clarify the above code snippet for other readers, I needed to edit the package="..." attribute in the manifest and give it a different package name.